# run sbt command in a scope of a sub project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project with sub projects.
there are 2 ways to run a task on a specific sub project:
1. `sbt proj1/compile`
2. `sbt "project proj1" compile`

but if I define a command, for example:

```
def hello = Command.command("hello") { state =>
  println("Hi!")
  state
}
```

running it with `sbt "project prog1" hello` works,
but whne I run `sbt prog1/hello` I get the following error:

```
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: hello (similar: shellPrompt)
[error] proj1/hello
[error]                    ^
```

is there a reason for this discrepancy?
any way to make `sbt prog1/hello` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that defining custom task in settings of project:

```
lazy val customTask = taskKey[Unit]("My custom task")
lazy val `proj1` = project
  .settings(
    customTask:= {println("Hello")}
  )
```

after you will can use: sbt prog1/customTask

Comment: I want to update the state of the project settings in the command, and that is not possible in a task